# Things to keep in mind to change after cloning a Ubuntu server vm

Tags: vmware

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server running on an vmware workstation 8.
Due to my time limitations I can not afford to install new servers so I decided that I must  make 10 clones of it with the exact same configuration.
What must I keep in mind to change besides the IP address, mac address and the hostname so that I don't cause any conflicts between the servers after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making 10 clones of an existing server you're still in the trade-off where spending a few hours now, deconstructing its setup and scripting it with Puppet/Chef/Juju/etc and setting up maintenance and monitoring is easily going to offset the time you would spend manually chasing around after servers running individual package updates and wondering what went wrong when a service drops off.

It's really boring sysop stuff... But as I say, it'll pay for itself within a couple of months and by the end of next year you'll either be thanking me for suggesting it or cursing yourself for ignoring it. IMO that applies when you're dealing with any more than two computers. It doesn't take that long to get this stuff set up.

But IP address and hostnames are the big two. If you're running network-provisioning services like a DHCP, that's going to cause issues but assuming these are clients, you're probably not going to see any more problems immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. They are all tiny webservers with 1G of RAM and will be used by students and they all have static IP addresses. The thing is that the first one is already set up and I don't want to set it up all over again, as I am a Cisco admin and only occasional Linux user - 50% of the stuff I do on a linux machine is by goggling it first on how it's done :) - you get the idea. The initial Apache setup was painful enough so I just want to spare myself the time.

Answer (score 2):

And if it is Ubuntu 18.04 using DHCP and netplan (or you may want to do it anyway), just spent a while trying to figure our why my clone with different MAC addresses got the same ip from a dhcp server...

You have to change /etc/machine-id to give it a unique name by using

```
sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
```

Comment: I needed to `mv /etc/machine-id  /etc/machine-id.old`  first on my Ubuntu 20.04, then `systemd-machine-id-setup && netplan apply`

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, yes IP addresses and hostnames are obvious.  However, please be sure you delete /root/.ssh so those VMs don't have your SSH keys to get back into your main server.   Same thing if you create that main server VM as your personal server -- remote user accounts that don't need to be on the server.

Since time is important, is space important?  How about a new server,. give student logins to it and have them SSH to their own lightweight container where they can't affect your server.  See man -k lxc.   FYI, Docker was started using a simple linux container tool called "lxc".

(1) create brand new Ubuntu or CentOS server; and (2) use Linux Container (lxc "lxc create {servername} -t ubuntu" on your Ubuntu VM.  It will let you easily create 10 containers that can be logged into.

"Oli" raised good point about scripting.  See many of the tutorials on digital ocean on using Ansible to create a LXC lab with web servers and database servers.  They have both Apache and Nginx versions of the tutorials if you need web server.

Good luck!

Larry